Python TensorFlow, infinite loop in the first epoch
I've got a Python program that uses TensorFlow, but when I run it the first epoch runs, but the next one doesn't. I'm not sure why.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

!pwd

"""Doit être dans '/content'

Importation des datasets
"""

!pip install tqdm

import os
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm  # Importation de tqdm pour la barre de progression

# Liste des URLs des fichiers à télécharger
urls = [
    "https://service.scedc.caltech.edu/ftp/Ross_FinalTrainedModels/scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_test.hdf5",
    "https://service.scedc.caltech.edu/ftp/Ross_FinalTrainedModels/scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_train.hdf5"
]

# Fonction pour télécharger un fichier avec suivi de l'avancement
def download_file(url):
    # Récupérer le nom du fichier à partir de l'URL
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]

    # Vérifier si le fichier existe déjà dans le répertoire courant
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        print(f"Le fichier {file_name} existe déjà.")
        return

    # Télécharger le fichier
    print(f"Téléchargement du fichier {file_name}...")
    try:
        # Effectuer la requête GET pour récupérer le fichier
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Vérifie si la requête a réussi (code 200)

        # Obtenir la taille du fichier à télécharger
        total_size = int(response.headers.get('Content-Length', 0))

        # Utiliser tqdm pour afficher une barre de progression
        with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
            # Télécharger par morceaux de 1024 octets
            for data in tqdm(response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024),
                              total=total_size // 1024,  # Calculer le nombre d'itérations
                              unit='KB',  # Unité de la barre de progression
                              desc=file_name):  # Le nom du fichier comme description de la barre
                f.write(data)

        print(f"Fichier {file_name} téléchargé avec succès.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors du téléchargement de {file_name}: {e}")

# Télécharger chaque fichier
for url in urls:
    download_file(url)

!ls -l

"""Les fichiers suivants doivent apparaitre :

scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_test.hdf5

scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_train.hdf5

Analyse des données contenues dans les datasets
"""

!pip install h5py

import h5py

def afficher_contenu_hdf5(fichier_hdf5):
    try:
        # Ouvrir le fichier HDF5 en mode lecture
        with h5py.File(fichier_hdf5, 'r') as f:
            print(f"Contenu du fichier HDF5: {fichier_hdf5}\n")

            # Fonction récursive pour afficher le contenu de chaque groupe
            def explorer_groupe(groupe, indent=0):
                # Afficher le nom du groupe
                print('  ' * indent + f"Group: {groupe}")

                # Explorer les datasets dans ce groupe
                for nom, dataset in groupe.items():
                    if isinstance(dataset, h5py.Dataset):
                        print('  ' * (indent + 1) + f"Dataset: {nom}, Shape: {dataset.shape}, Type: {dataset.dtype}")
                        # Optionnel : afficher les premiers éléments du dataset
                        print('  ' * (indent + 2) + f"Premiers éléments: {dataset[:5]}")  # Affiche les 5 premiers éléments

                # Explorer les sous-groupes
                for nom, sous_groupe in groupe.items():
                    if isinstance(sous_groupe, h5py.Group):
                        explorer_groupe(sous_groupe, indent + 1)

            # Lancer l'exploration du fichier principal
            explorer_groupe(f)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors de l'ouverture du fichier HDF5: {e}")

# Exemple d'utilisation avec un fichier HDF5 (remplacer par ton propre fichier)
# fichier = 'ton_fichier.hdf5'  # Remplace par le chemin vers ton fichier HDF5
# afficher_contenu_hdf5(fichier)

fichier = 'scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_train.hdf5'
afficher_contenu_hdf5(fichier)

fichier = 'scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_test.hdf5'
afficher_contenu_hdf5(fichier)

"""Importation des bibliothèques"""

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import h5py
import datetime

"""Importation des données pour utilisation dans le modèle"""

def data_generator(file_path, batch_size=10000, scaler_X=None):
    with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as file:
        total_samples = file['X'].shape[0]
        X = file['X']
        Y = file['fm']

        print(f"Total samples: {total_samples}")  # Affichez la taille totale

        while True:
            for start in range(0, total_samples, batch_size):
                end = min(start + batch_size, total_samples)

                X_batch = X[start:end]
                Y_batch = Y[start:end]

                if scaler_X is None:
                    scaler_X = StandardScaler()
                    X_batch_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X_batch)
                else:
                    X_batch_scaled = scaler_X.transform(X_batch)

                print(f"Batch: {start}-{end} (X_batch shape: {X_batch_scaled.shape})")  # Affichez la taille du lot
                yield X_batch_scaled, Y_batch

# Calcul dynamique de `steps_per_epoch`
def get_steps_per_epoch(file_path, batch_size=10000):
    with h5py.File(file_path, 'r') as file:
        total_samples = file['X'].shape[0]  # Nombre total d'échantillons
        steps_per_epoch = total_samples // batch_size
        if total_samples % batch_size != 0:  # Si la division n'est pas exacte
            steps_per_epoch += 1  # Ajouter une étape supplémentaire pour les restes
        return steps_per_epoch

"""Création de la fonction qui génère le modèle"""

def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(600,), name='layers_input'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='layers_dense'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='layers_dropout'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='layers_dense_2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name='layers_dropout_2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='layers_output')
    ])
    return model

model = create_model()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# Vérifiez si le modèle est compilé correctement
if model.optimizer:
    print(f"Optimiseur : {model.optimizer}")
else:
    print("Le modèle n'est pas compilé correctement")

"""Initialisation de la sauvegarde des logs"""

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# Load the TensorBoard notebook extension
# %load_ext tensorboard

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# Reload TensorBoard extension
# %reload_ext tensorboard

# Clear any logs from previous runs
!rm -rf ./logs/

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0)

train_file_path = 'scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_train.hdf5'
steps_per_epoch = get_steps_per_epoch(train_file_path, batch_size=10000)
print(f"Steps per epoch: {steps_per_epoch}")  # Affichez les étapes par époque
test_file_path = 'scsn_p_2000_2017_6sec_0.5r_pick_test.hdf5'

scaler_X = StandardScaler()

model.fit(
    data_generator(train_file_path, batch_size=1000),
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch//2,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=data_generator(test_file_path, batch_size=1000),
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
)

# Commented out IPython magic to ensure Python compatibility.
# %tensorboard --logdir logs/fit

Here's an example of what I get:
Total samples: 3635436
Batch: 0-1000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 1000-2000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Epoch 1/2
  1/182 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 22s 126ms/step - accuracy: 0.7280 - loss: 0.6024Batch: 2000-3000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
...
...
179/182 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 37ms/step - accuracy: 0.7474 - loss: 0.6028Batch: 182000-183000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 183000-184000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 184000-185000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
181/182 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 37ms/step - accuracy: 0.7475 - loss: 0.6028Batch: 185000-186000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
182/182 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 37ms/step - accuracy: 0.7475 - loss: 0.6027Total samples: 1211812
Batch: 0-1000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 1000-2000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 2000-3000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 3000-4000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 4000-5000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 5000-6000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 6000-7000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 7000-8000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 8000-9000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 9000-10000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 10000-11000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
Batch: 11000-12000 (X_batch shape: (1000, 600))
... (infinit)

I think the problem may come from data loading, but not where precisely, because normally the epoch should stop on its own.
I'd like my program to be able to iterate over any period of time.
I tried looking at the 'steps_per_epoch' parameter to stop my epoch but my attempts didn't work.
